# Is there any way to use WebBrowser Class (Band Objects) to write the DOM?

Tags: internet-explorer, dom

I have created a IE toolbar using BandObjects (using COM assembly -Interop.SHDocVw.dll) to implement the custom search functionality. Toolbar contains a search box which takes input and returns the result. Results has to be fetched from two or more search engines and then combined together before showing them on browser. So as you can see I need to write the document object model of Explorer window with my combined results.

I am unable to see any property or method provided by WebBrowser Class which let me to write DOM. Could anyone please suggest the best possible solution to this task. A link to the API of BandObjects would be great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Document object of the currently loaded page to modify its DOM. Having said that, writing Internet Explorer extensions in C# is strongly discouraged. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/21/agcore-addon-hangs-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw for your input. Even I was not very sure about using C# for this task. Would you advise using Visual C++ for same? I would appreciate if you provide some pointer.

Comment: Document Object property is read only and not available for update.